# React Native / Redux Toolkit state rendering is always one step behind

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've been having some state management problems with an app I am building using React Native, so I decided to try Redux-Toolkit. After watching a couple of tutorials on YouTube, I was able to implement the functionality I needed. Unfortunately, it seems like when I set a new state to a variable using dispatch, the state is always one step/state behind. For example, as per my code, the variable "term" has an initial value of "spring". There are three buttons (spring, summer, and fall). If I click on "summer", an alert will display "spring", which is the initial value, and if I click on any of the three buttons afterward, "summer" will be displayed (which was the previous state). The state displayed is always the previous state. Is there a problem with my code logic? Basically, The three buttons will be used to change an SQLite query filter depending on the term/semester. Please see a re-creation of the problem I am having with my code below. Thank You

**TermSlice.js**

```
    import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    
    export const termSlice = createSlice({
      name: "termChanger",
      initialState: {
        term: 'Spring'
      },
      reducers: {
        setTerm: (state, action) => {
          state.term = action.payload;
        }
      }
    });
    
    export const { setTerm } = termSlice.actions;
    export default termSlice.reducer;
```

**Store.js**

```
    import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import termSlice from "./TermSlice";
    
    export default configureStore({
      reducer: {
        termChanger : termSlice
      },
    });
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text} from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";

import {useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { setTerm } from "../redux/TermSlice";

export default function Home() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { term } = useSelector((state) => state.termChanger);

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Button onPress={() => {
          alert(term);
        }} title="Term">Term</Button>

        <Button onPress={() => {
          dispatch(setTerm("Spring"));
          alert(term);
        }} title="Spring">Spring</Button>

        <Button onPress={() => {
          dispatch(setTerm("Summer"));
          alert(term);
        }} title="Summer">Summer</Button>

        <Button onPress={() => {
          dispatch(setTerm("Fall"));
          alert(term);
        }} title="Fall">Fall</Button>

        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import store from "./src/redux/Store";
import Home from "./src/screens/Home";

export default function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Home />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dispatch(setTerm("Spring"))` action and the `alert(term)` functions are both called in the same render cycle so `alert(term)` is using the value of `term` from before the `dispatch`.

Your `useSelector` hook *is* getting updated.  You can `alert` with the new value by using a `useEffect` hook that responds to changes in the value of `term`.

Or just stick to your "Term" button.  This button will get the correct value because it not also changing the `term` value that it is displaying.

```
export default function Home() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const term = useSelector((state) => state.termChanger.term);

  useEffect(() => {
    alert(term);
  }, [term]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button onPress={() => alert(term)} title="Term">
        Term
      </Button>

      <Button onPress={() => dispatch(setTerm("Spring"))} title="Spring">
        Spring
      </Button>

      <Button onPress={() => dispatch(setTerm("Summer"))} title="Summer">
        Summer
      </Button>

      <Button onPress={() => dispatch(setTerm("Fall"))} title="Fall">
        Fall
      </Button>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are right, thank you. I was using the alerts for debugging and didn't realize they were using the state when I clicked the button... I assumed they would use the state after the dispatch happened.